# Need a groovy code to convert GB value to MB value

Tags: groovy

package P;

import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class C {
static final double GB_IN_MB = 1000;

```
PrintStream out;
Scanner in;

C() {
    out = new PrintStream(System.out);
    in = new Scanner(System.in);
}

void start() {
    out.printf("Enter the number of GB(s): ");
    double numberOfGBs = in.nextDouble();
    in.close();

    double numberOfMBs = numberOfGBs * GB_IN_MB;
    out.printf("%f GB equals %f MB\n", numberOfGBs, numberOfMBs);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new C().start();

}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Could you please clarify your problem in more detail?